# Will current flow through the resistor in the image?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Would current flow through the resistor below?

$\hspace{150px}$[$
{\def\place#1#2#3{\smash{\rlap{\hskip{#1px}\raise{#2px}{\color{black}{#3}}}}}}
%
\place{145}{170}{\Large{R}}
%
\place{150}{77}{\Large{V}}
%
\place{50}{145}{{\huge{\bullet}}}
\place{67}{149}{\leftarrow \hspace{-5px} {\large{\textbf{A}}}}
%
\place{255}{155}{{\huge{\bullet}}}
\place{223}{158}{{\large{\textbf{B}}}\hspace{-5px} \rightarrow}
$[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxXsS.jpg)

The power source is an ideal cell without internal resistance, and the wires are also ideal.

I thought that current won't flow through the resistor because there is no potential difference between the points $\text{A}$ and $\text{B}$, but I am not sure.

Comment: Is the battery symbol meant to represent an ideal voltage source, or a real battery?

Comment: Yes, it will. The wire from A to B has some very low but real resistance, so some small amount of current will flow in the R.

Comment: @C.TowneSpringer, in the context of ideal circuit theory, the wire from $A$ to $B$ has zero resistance.  There is evidence that the OP is considering the ideal case as evidenced by the statement "because there is no potential difference between the points A and B".  In this context, the OP's conclusion that there is no current through the resistor is correct.  Further, *if* the connecting wire is non-ideal and thus has some very low but real resistance, that small resistance should be *explicitly* shown as an ideal, small resistance.  This is (in my experience) how it's done in EE.

Comment: Jhayakhar, as @ThePhoton hints, the problem with your schematic is that, in the context of ideal circuit theory, one cannot place a zero resistance in parallel with an ideal voltage source without contradiction, e.g., 12V = 0V.  Either show explicitly the resistance of the connecting wire or the internal resistance of the voltage source if you want a physical answer to your question.

Comment: Related: [Would current flow through a 0 Ohm wire?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/398628/22927)

Comment: You double-labeled the same point: $\text{Point A}$ and $\text{Point B}$ are **_literally_** the same point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different loops for this circuit, and it looks like there should be only two independent loops, but I find it helpful to look at three different loops for the "loop rule" to understand what "would happen."

Loop 1 (pass through the battery and along the wire with the resistor and back to the battery): 
$$
V=IR
$$

Loop 2 (go from your point A to point B through the resistor and back to point A via the wire):
$$
IR=0
$$

Loop 3 (pass through the battery and along the wire back to the battery):
$$
V=0
$$

Seems like such a circuit can't "exist" except when $V=0$, which means $I=0$.

---

On the other hand, if the wire isn't "perfect" but actually a small finite resistance "r" (through current which $i = I_0 - I$ flows) then the equations are:

Loop 1 (pass through the battery and along the wire with the resistor and back to the battery): 
$$
V=IR
$$

Loop 2 (go from your point A to point B through the resistor and back to point A via the wire):
$$
IR=ir
$$

Loop 3 (pass through the battery and along the wire back to the battery):
$$
V=ir
$$

In both sets of equation there are really only two independent equations and we need some more rules, e.g., the junction rule ($I_0=I+i$) and the equivalent resistance rule ($1/R_0 = 1/R + 1/r$), to make much more progress.

If we use the second rule above we can also write:
$$
I/i = r/R
$$
(as another answer has also stated). In this case it again appears that we can say $I=0$ if $r\to 0$.

---

But regardless, the main issue is that if you presuppose an ideal wire connected directly between the terminals of a "ideal cell", as in the picture, there is actually no way to sustain a non-zero potential difference across the "ideal cell."

You can also understand this logical problem from the definition of electrical potential. If you have a perfect conductor (the ideal wire) connected from one terminal of a "battery" to another the potential difference across the terminals must actually be zero since the electric field inside a perfect conductor is zero and I can go all the way from one terminal to another inside the perfect conductor:

$$
V = \int E\cdot dl = \int 0 = 0
$$

---

So, basically, yes, you are correct, the current I is zero. However, this is because the picture cannot make sense unless the ideal cell has $V=0$. It is just absurd otherwise; we can make absurd drawings, we can make absurd statements, we can pose absurd questions. For example, I could ask you: "What is the square root of a hockey puck?" Clearly this is absurd, and really there is no good answer since there is no good question.

Answer (score 3):

If the lower wire from A to B is not assumed to be of zero resistance then definitely current would flow through both of them.

If the upper net resistance is $R_\text{upper}$ and the lower is $R_\text{lower}$ then 
$$
\frac{I_\text{upper}}{I_\text{lower}}~=~\frac{R_\text{lower}}{R_\text{upper}}
\,.$$

Comment: To be sure, what of the case that the lower wire is *ideal* as the OP evidently assumes?

Answer (score 2):

The essential problem here is that you haven't specified whether the schematic is an *ideal circuit model* or not.

If ideal, then you have drawn a contradiction - it is *well known* (in EE) that an ideal wire across an ideal (non-zero) voltage source results in a contradiction, e.g., $12\,\mathrm{V} = 0\,\mathrm{V}$.

If non-ideal then, to solve this, you must model the non-ideal behavior with additional ideal circuit elements.

For example, if the voltage source has finite short-circuit current $I_{SC}$, you must add an *internal resistance* $r_S$ in series with the voltage source such that

$$r_S  = \frac{V}{I_{SC}}$$

Further, if the wire in parallel with the resistance $R$ is non-ideal, you should add a small resistance $r_w$ in series with the wire.  To be sure, you might add additional small resistances in series with the other two connecting wires.

In summary, to properly solve *physical* circuits (with circuit laws) using *ideal* circuit elements, you must make sure that you've added the additional ideal circuit elements to account for the non-ideal behavior of physical circuit elements, e.g., physical wires have non-zero resistance, physical voltage sources have finite short-circuit current.

For AC circuits, it's even more complicated as you must also add 'parasitic' inductance and capacitance to account for facts like, e.g., physical capacitors, inductors, and resistors have a *Q* and a resonance frequency.

Answer (score 0):

We can apply Kirchhoff's loop rule to the small loop containing only the resistor and the wire connecting point A and B, as shown in the following figure.[image]

Assume the current passing the resistor is $I_R$ and the current passing the wire below is $I_r$, then we have $I_R R - I_r r = 0$ since there is no potential source in this loop. (The direction of $I_R$ and $I_r$ are both defined to be from A to B)

Therefore, if the wire below the resistor is ideal, then $r = 0$ and $I_R = \frac{I_r r}{R} = 0$, and no current flow through the resistor. But if we take the resistence of the wire into account, then (this time assume that $R$ is the total resistence of the upper path from A to B) based on the same equation above, there indeed is current flowing through the resistor (although very small, usually undetectable.)

Comment: Have you properly accounted for the case that the voltage source has zero internal resistance too?

Comment: No. Sorry that I did not focus on the voltage source since I thought that concentrating on the smaller loop without a voltage source is simplier.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a short answer: yes, the current won't flow. Your argument of no voltage across it is true. IT can also be shown using the intensity for a branch in a parallel of two resistances with $R_2=0$. So yes, ideally, it won't flow. However you will burn the source unless you place any "useful" resistance somewhere.